# Sending collectionView data to outlets in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have an array of pics, names and buttons in a collection view cell that saves to my trainerArray.swift file.

When i click on button 1 in the collectionViewCell, i want to be segued to another VC that displays the picture for the cell in which i clicked on in VC1.

How can i handle this?

i tried connecting outlets and passing the data in prepareForSegue but it gave me error "cannot connect labels to repeating content"

I need to pass the image in the collectionViewCell as well as the label content to the next VC.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are getting that error because you're trying to create an outlet for a label in a table view cell in a view controller. You should create a subclass of UITableViewCell and create the outlet there. Then change your prototype cell to that subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to modify another view controller's view objects. Treat a view controller's views as private, and only available to the view controller itself.

What you want to do is add properties to your view controller's header and set those properties in prepareForSegue. Then in your view controller's viewWillAppear, fetch the values from your properties and install them into your views as appropriate.